# How to get store opening hours in local timezone from given date-time response? - SWIFT 5

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, timezone-offset, xcode12

I'm getting opening hours from Json response and I want to calculate if store is open or not at the moment?

My Json response is looks like this:

```
{
"endDay":2,
"endTime":"03:00",
"startDay":1,
"startTime":"11:00"
},
{
"endDay":3,
"endTime":"03:00",
"startDay":2,
"startTime":"11:00"
},
...
```

I have 7 dictionaries (Sunday to Monday) in this Json response, where `startDay` and `endDay` is representing weekday. (Sunday = 0, and so on.)

Above all times are in UTC, but I want to calculate in my local timezone.

**Actual problem is figuring out the difference in 'Day' conversion. I can convert just time, but don't have idea how to manage the timezone difference in calculating next Day or previous day?**

I'm using XCode 12 and Swift 5.
Appreciate your help in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is conversion of weekday and time in GMT into PST time zone:

```
let weekday = 2 // weekday == 1 is Sunday
let hour = 4 // 4:00 am in GMT+0
let minute = 0 // in GMT+0
guard let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) else { return }
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian) // Should be the calendar that is used by your server
calendar.timeZone = timeZone
let date = Date()
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(Set(arrayLiteral: Calendar.Component.weekday,
                                                 Calendar.Component.hour,
                                                 Calendar.Component.minute), from: date)
var dateComponentsDiff = DateComponents()
dateComponentsDiff.day = weekday - dateComponents.weekday!
dateComponentsDiff.hour = hour - dateComponents.hour!
dateComponentsDiff.minute = minute - dateComponents.minute!
guard let arbitraryDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponentsDiff, to: date),
      let pstTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PST") else { return }
let pstDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: pstTimeZone, from: arbitraryDate)
print("WEEK DAY: \(pstDateComponents.weekday!)\nTIME: \(pstDateComponents.hour!):\(pstDateComponents.minute!)")
```

Output:

```
WEEK DAY: 1
TIME: 20:0
```

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. It's not exactly what I want, but this helped me to solve my issue.